# Gstreamer AAC ADTS with variable bitrate time duration calculation

Tags: gstreamer, aac, bitrate, adts

> I am using gstreamer for my aac files . I want to know how to
>   calculate exact duration for AAC file with ADTS format(ie variable
>   bitrate) in fast way. Right now I am calculating estimated duration at
>   the start of frame which gives more error for large filesize. Can anyone suggest me algorithm for 
>   this?